# ConfigurationManager adds unexpected items to system.web section

Tags: configurationmanager, system.web

I'm modifying the connection string on the Web.config file during a web installer custom action.

This is the code snippet that is doing the job

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = path;

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var connectionsection = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings;

ConnectionStringSettings connectionstring = connectionsection[connStringName];
if (connectionsection != null)
    connectionsection.Remove(connStringName);

connectionstring = new ConnectionStringSettings(connStringName, newValue, "System.Data.SqlClient");
connectionsection.Add(connectionstring);

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

So far so good, this is actually working, but it is also adding some items to "system.web" section, which are causing the error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineOnly' beyond machine.config.
Source Error: 

Line 46:     <authorization />
Line 47:     <clientTarget />
Line 48:     <deployment />
Line 49:     <deviceFilters />
Line 50:     <fullTrustAssemblies />
```

When I manually remove some sections added by the ConfigurationManager `<deployment />`, `<protocols />` and `<processModel />` the error goes away. So I just need the ConfigurationManager to not create this sections. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be clear it manually in XML after ConfigurationManager dirtying the file, but this is not the most appropriate, I think

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);

var document = XDocument.Load(configPath);
var systemWeb = document.Root.Element("system.web");

XElement element;
element = systemWeb.Element("deployment");
if (element != null)
    element.Remove();

element = systemWeb.Element("protocols");
if (element != null)
    element.Remove();

element = systemWeb.Element("processModel");
if (element != null)
    element.Remove();

document.Save(configPath);
```